# Codeginiter populate checkboxes according to database row count

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to `Codeigniter` and its development. I have a database called `diy` and a table called `Tags`
with  columns: `tagid`, `catogoryid` ,`tagname` ,`questionid`. I have inserted values into tagged and tagname.

In my view I retrieve `tagname` values and I wish to populate checkboxes according to tagnames. But I'm getting a null array.

askview.php( view)

```
<?php
//load database here

this->db->where('tagname', '4');

$q = $this->db->get('Tags');
$data = $q->result_array();

var_dump($data);

// echo($data[1]['tagname']);


$chk_group =$data ;

//  var_dump($chk_group);

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($chk_group); $i++) {
   $val = $chk_group[$i];
   echo "<br>";
   echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $val . '" name="chk_group[]">' . $val;
   echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

Output is: `array(0) { }`

Comment: Please show the result you get in `$data` !!!

Comment: @AfghanWiz - array(0) { } im having null array dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following way will work

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

```
    <?php
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM Tags');

    $co=1;
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $chk_group[$co]=$row->tagname;
     ++$co;

   }


   for ($i = 1; $i <= count($chk_group); $i++) {
   $val = $chk_group[$i];
echo "<br>";
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $val . '" name="chk_group[]">' . $val;
                                        echo "</br>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code must work well, **IF** there is anything to be processed and displayed as checkboxes on the page!

The better approch could be to check if you are getting any records from your queries and make your next processes accordingly!

```
this->db->where('tagname', '4'); // BTW, make sure it is not tagid ;)

$q = $this->db->get('Tags');
if($q->num_rows > 0){
    $data = $q->result_array();

    $chk_group =$data ;

    //  var_dump($chk_group);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($chk_group); $i++) {
       $val = $chk_group[$i];
       echo "<br>";
       echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $val . '" name="chk_group[]">' . $val;
       echo "</br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "There is no such tag available in our records!";
}
```

Comment: this->db->where('tagname', '4'); i think i have problem with 4 here i think i have four coloums such as tagid, catogoryid ,tagname ,questionid is it right

Answer (score 0):

You want to select from table tags where tagname ='4' is that right?
there is no problem with your code. I think the problem on the data.